# Home Page is rendering twice in Angular 11 using router-outlet

Tags: angular

I want to show my login page without header, but the home component is rendering twice, I'm using Home Component to my home page, not app component but still duplicating. Investigating a little I know `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag makes the home appears twice, but I don't know how fix this. I use `*ngIf` in order to hide the header when the login page is active.

***app.component.html***

```
<app-header *ngIf="hiHead"></app-header>

<router-outlet></router-outlet> 
<app-footer></<app-footer>
```

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'cdls-app';
  hiHead: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // on route change to '/login', set the variable showHead to false
      router.events.forEach((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          if (event['url'] == '/login') {
            this.hiHead = false;
          } else {
            console.log("NU")
            this.hiHead = true;
          }
        }
      });
    }
}

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

***app-routing.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterformComponent } from './registerform/registerform.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'registro', component: RegisterformComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: 
    [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

***home.component.html***

```
         <div class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light uk-text-middle" tabindex="-1" uk-slideshow="autoplay: true autoplay-interval: 6000 animation: push pause-on-hover: false">

            <ul class="uk-slideshow-items">
                <li>
                    <img style="filter:brightness(92%)" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4039155/pexels-photo-4039155.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-cottonbro-4039155.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="" uk-cover uk-img>
                    <div style="padding-top:14%; padding-left: 50%; position:absolute; background-color:transparent;" class="uk-card uk-card-body uk-text-middle" uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-right; repeat: true">
                        <h3 style="font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:5vw; color: #fbf005" class="uk-card-title uk-text-middle">Familias</h3>
                    </div>
                        
                    <div style="position:absolute; background-color:transparent;" class="" uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-left; repeat: true">
                        <p style="margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-top:22%; padding-left:50%; padding-right:30px; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-size:3.2vw; color:#fdfefe">Somos una comunidad que se apoya unos a otros. Conéctate con otras familias</p>
                        <h3 style="padding-top:0px; margin-top:0; padding-left:50%; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;" class="uk-card-title"><a style="text-decoration: none; margin-top:4px; padding-left:0; color: #fbf005; font-size:2.5vw; background-color:transparent;" class="uk-card-title uk-text-left" href="#"><i class="fab fa-leanpub"></i>  Aprende Más</a></h3>


                    </div>
                    
                </li>    
               
                <li>
                    <img style="filter:brightness(92%)" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5638612/pexels-photo-5638612.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-askar-abayev-5638612.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="" uk-cover uk-img>
                    <div style="padding-top:14%; padding-left: 50%; position:absolute; background-color:transparent;" class="uk-card uk-card-body uk-text-middle" uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-bottom; repeat: true">
                        <h3 style="font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:5vw; color: #0548fb" class="uk-card-title uk-text-middle">Profesionales</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div style="position:absolute; background-color:transparent;" class="" uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-top; repeat: true">
                        <p style="margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-top:22%; padding-left:50%; padding-right:30px; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-size:3.2vw; color:#fdfefe">Somos el punto de contacto con otros profesionales de la salud, únete a nosotros</p>
                         <h3 style="padding-top:0px; margin-top:0; padding-left:50%; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;" class="uk-card-title"><a style="text-decoration: none; margin-top:4px; padding-left:0; color: #0548fb; font-size:2.5vw; background-color:transparent;" class="uk-card-title uk-text-left" href="#"><i class="fas fa-users"></i>  Conéctate</a></h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img style="filter:brightness(92%)" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4386466/pexels-photo-4386466.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-karolina-grabowska-4386466.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="" uk-cover uk-img>
                    <div style="padding-top:14%; padding-left: 50%; position:absolute; background-color:transparent;" class="uk-card uk-card-body uk-text-middle" uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-top; repeat: true">
                        <h3 style="font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold; font-size:5vw; color:#fb053d;" class="uk-card-title uk-text-middle">Investigación</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top:22%; padding-left:50%; padding-right:30px; position:absolute; background-color:transparent;" class="" uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; repeat: true">
                        <p style="margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0;font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-size:3.2vw; color:#fdfefe">Investigamos para conocer más sobre CdLS con el apoyo de profesionales</p>
                        <h3 style="padding-top:0px; margin-top:0; padding-left:0%; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;" class="uk-card-title"><a style="text-decoration: none; margin-top:4px; padding-left:0; color: #fb053d; font-size:2.5vw; background-color:transparent;" class="uk-card-title uk-text-left" href="#"><i class="fas fa-dna"></i>  Conéctate</a></h3>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slideshow-item="previous"></a>
            <a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slideshow-item="next"></a>

        </div>

<div uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; target: .uk-card-body; delay: 500; repeat: true">
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-body uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l uk-text-center" style="padding:30px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:30px;">
    <h2 class="uk-card-title uk-text-center" style="padding-left:30px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; color: #00000; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">¿Tienes Algún Familiar Diagnósticado con CdLS?</h2>
    <p class="uk-text-center" style="width:70%; padding-left:30px; padding-right:0px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; color: #17202a; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; ">El síndrome de Cornelia de Lange ocurre en aproximadamente 1 de cada 10,000 nacimientos, actualmente en Colombia se han identificado alrededor de 100 casos, en los que la Fundación ha ayudado a familias con pacientes con esta rara enfermedad.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="uk-child-width-1-3@s uk-grid-match" uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-bottom; target: .uk-card; delay: 300; repeat: true">
<div class="uk-card uk-card-default" style="background-color:#fdfefe">
    <div class="uk-card-header" style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0; padding-top:0">
        <div class="uk-grid-small uk-flex-middle" uk-grid>
            <div class="uk-width-auto">
                <img class="" width="" height="" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/8944291/pexels-photo-8944291.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-anastasia-shuraeva-8944291.jpg&fm=jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-expand">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom uk-text-center" style="color:#1b4f72; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold">Familias</h3>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-card-body">
        <p>Nuestra fuerza proviene de nuestra comunidad de familias que se apoyan unos a otros. Podemos conectarte con otras familias CdLS que atraviesan por retos similares</p>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-card-footer uk-text-center">
        <a href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-text uk-text-center" style="font-weight:bold; color:#1b4f72;"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Conoce Más</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="uk-card uk-card-default" style="background-color:#fdfefe">
    <div class="uk-card-header" style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0; padding-top:0">
        <div class="uk-grid-small uk-flex-middle" uk-grid>
            <div class="uk-width-auto">
                <img class="" width="" height="" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5327653/pexels-photo-5327653.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-thirdman-5327653.jpg&fm=jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-expand">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom uk-text-center" style="color:#1b4f72; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold">Profesionales</h3>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-card-body">
        <p>Si eres profesional en ciencias de la salud, únete a nosotros y conéctate con otros profesionales en el campo de estudio del sindrome del CdLS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-card-footer uk-text-center">
        <a href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-text uk-text-center" style="font-weight:bold; color:#1b4f72;"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i> Conoce Más</a>
    </div>   
</div>

<div class="uk-card uk-card-default" style="background-color:#fdfefe">
    <div class="uk-card-header" style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0; padding-top:0">
        <div class="uk-grid-small uk-flex-middle" uk-grid>
            <div class="uk-width-auto">
                <img class="" width="" height="" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4033304/pexels-photo-4033304.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-edward-jenner-4033304.jpg&fm=jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-expand">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom uk-text-center" style="color:#1b4f72; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold">Investigación</h3>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-card-body">
        <p>Realizamos investigaciones para conocer más sobre el CdLS con el apoyo de profesionales en ciencias de la salud</p>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-card-footer uk-text-center" style="">
        <a href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-text uk-text-center" style="font-weight:bold; color:#1b4f72;"><i class="fas fa-dna"></i> Conoce Más</a>
    </div>

    
</div>
</div>

<div uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; target: .uk-card-body; delay: 500; repeat: true">
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-body uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l uk-text-center" style="margin-top:0px;">
    <h2 class="uk-card-title uk-text-center" style="padding-left:20px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; color: #00000; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">¿Quieres Ayudar? Únete y Sé Parte del Cambio, Ayúdando a Otros</h2>
    
    </div>
</div>

<div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-grid-collapse uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-margin" style="" uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-left; repeat: true" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-card-media-left uk-cover-container">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3204051/pexels-photo-3204051.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-harrison-haines-3204051.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="" uk-cover>
        <canvas width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="uk-card-body">
            <h3 class="uk-card-title">Donaciones</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; target: .uk-card-body; delay: 500; repeat: true">
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-body uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l" style="margin-top:0px; padding:0;">
    <h2 class="uk-card-title uk-text-center" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; color: #00000; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold;"></h2>
    
    </div>
</div>

<div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-grid-collapse uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-margin" uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-slide-right; repeat: true" uk-grid>
    <div class="uk-flex-last@s uk-card-media-right uk-cover-container">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/3184397/pexels-photo-3184397.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-fauxels-3184397.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="" uk-cover>
        <canvas width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="uk-card-body">
            <h3 class="uk-card-title">Voluntariado</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; target: .uk-card-body; delay: 500; repeat: true">
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-body uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l uk-text-center" style="margin-top:0px;">
    <h2 class="uk-card-title uk-text-center" style="padding-left:20px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; color: #00000; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">Casos CdLS en Colombia</h2>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="uk-cover-container uk-height-medium uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l uk-text-center uk-responsive-height uk-responsive-width">
    <iframe  width="60%" height="auto" src="https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/7c8d7d55-ee22-4185-852a-526a8c6f67da/page/RWqWC" frameborder="0" style="border:0; overflow: hidden;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


<div uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; target: .uk-card-body; delay: 500; repeat: true">
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-body uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l uk-text-center" style="margin-top:30px;">
    <h2 class="uk-card-title uk-text-center" style="padding-left:20px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; color: #00000; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">Somos Miembros Activos</h2>
    
    </div>
</div>




<div class="uk-width-xlarge uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l uk-container-center" style="padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; margin-left:auto: margin-right:auto; background-color: #f8f9f9">
<div style="margin-left:auto: margin-right:auto;" class="uk-position-relative uk-visible-toggle uk-light" tabindex="-1" uk-slider="autoplay: true; autoplay-interval: 0; velocity: 0.03; easing: linear; pause-on-hover: false; draggable: false;">

    <ul class="uk-slider-items uk-child-width-1-3 uk-child-width-1-3@m">
        <li>
            <div class="uk-panel uk-text-center" style="width:auto">
                <img data-src="assets/images/cdlsFederationLogo.png" alt="cdlsFederation"  style="height:8%; padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;  object-fit: cover; margin-left:auto: margin-right:auto" uk-img>
                <div class="uk-position-center uk-panel"><h1></h1></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="uk-panel uk-text-center uk-position-center">
                <img data-src="assets/images/Aliber.png" alt="" style="padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover;  object-fit:cover; margin-left:auto: margin-right:auto;"  uk-img>
                <div class="uk-position-center uk-panel"><h1></h1></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="uk-panel uk-text-center uk-position-center">
                <img data-src="assets/images/FenadecLogo.png" alt=""  style="padding-left:auto; padding-right:auto; width:80%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; object-fit:cover; margin-left:auto: margin-right:auto;" uk-img>
                <div class="uk-position-center uk-panel"><h1></h1></div>
            </div>
            
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="uk-panel uk-text-center uk-position-center">
                <img data-src="assets/images/EnHulogo.png" alt="" style="padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px; width:80%; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; object-fit: cover; margin-left:auto: margin-right:auto"  uk-img>
                <div class="uk-position-center uk-panel"><h1></h1></div>
            </div>

        </li>
       
    </ul>

    <a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous uk-slider-item="previous"></a>
    <a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover" href="#" uk-slidenav-next uk-slider-item="next"></a>

</div></div>


       
<div uk-grid uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; target: .uk-card-body; delay: 500; repeat: true">
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-body uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l" style="margin-top:0px;">
        <h2 class="uk-card-title uk-text-center" style="padding-left:30px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; color: #00000; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">¿Tienes Preguntas? Nosotros te las respondemos!</h2>
        <p class="uk-text-center" style="width:70%; padding-left:30px; padding-right:0px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; color: #17202a; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; ">Si necesitas asistencia, estamos aquí para ti!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l uk-text-center" style="margin-top:0; width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:30px;" uk-scrollspy="cls: uk-animation-fade; target: .uk-button-primary; delay: 500; repeat: true">
        <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-text-center">Déjanos tus datos</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

***login.component.html***

```
<body>

<div class="uk-child-width-1-1@s uk-light" uk-grid>
    <div>
        <div class="uk-background-cover uk-height-large uk-panel uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle uk-background-norepeat" style="background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/5792901/pexels-photo-5792901.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-yan-krukov-5792901.jpg&fm=jpg'); height:120vh">
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-width-1-2@m" style="margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px; background-color: #ffffff; border-radius:12px; width:450px">
    <div class="uk-card-header">
        <div class="uk-grid-small uk-flex-middle" uk-grid>
            <div class="uk-width-auto">
                <img class="uk-border-circle" width="80" height="80" data-src="/assets/images/logofundacion.png" uk-img>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-width-expand uk-text-center" style="width:100%;">
                <h3 class="uk-card-title uk-margin-remove-bottom uk-text-center" style="color:#1a5276; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold;">Inicio de Sesión</h3>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-card-body" style="background-color:#fffffff;">
        <form style="color:#212f3d;">
             <fieldset class="uk-fieldset" style="color:#212f3d;">

        <span class="uk-label uk-text-capitalize" style="color:#1a5276; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold">Usuario</span>
        <div class="uk-margin" style="color: #212f3d;">
        <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l">
        <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: user" style="color:#abb2b9"></span>
            <input class="uk-input" type="text" placeholder="usuario" style="border: 1px solid #abb2b9; color:#212f3d; border-radius:5px;">
        </div>
        </div>

        <span class="uk-label uk-text-capitalize" style="color:#1a5276; font-family:'Lato', sans-serif; font-weight:bold">Contraseña</span>
        <div class="uk-margin" style="color: #212f3d">
         <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-1@s uk-width-1-1@m uk-width-1-1@l">
            <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: lock" style="color:#abb2b9"></span>
            <input class="uk-input" type="text" placeholder="" style="border: 1px solid  #abb2b9; border-color: #abb2b9; color:#212f3d; border-radius:5px;">
        </div>
        </div>
        <span class="uk-label uk-text-capitalize" style="font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;">¿Todavía no tienes una cuenta? <a class="uk-link-text" href="/registro" style="color:#2874a6;"> Regístrate gratis</a></span>

    



    </fieldset>
</form>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-card-footer uk-text-center" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
        <button href="#" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-text-center" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:#2471a3; color:#fdfefe; border-radius:5px">Iniciar Sesión</button>
    </div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: If every component is rendered twice then look for superfluous <router-outlet> tags

Comment: If you make a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) we can more easily help you with your problem. I will look into it and update my answer when you do. Cheers

Comment: you have a lot of inline styles there - it is better code structure to use of your external css / scss files for your components as much as possible - some of the style declarations are long and wordy and make the html hard to read. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

While it might not help with rendering your page twice. I don't think using the router.events.foreach() is a good way to find out if you are on the login page.

For this you could use the data property on your route.

In the route:

```js
const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '/login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: { hiHead: false }
  }
]
```

To get the data:

```js
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ...
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hiHead = this.route.snapshot.data['hiHead']
    ...
}
```